# Get selected combobox item

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have two comboboxes that get their data from read-only views. How do I get the selected values once the form is submitted?

All of the Vaadin samples dealing with comboboxes use data binding to entity classes but I'm not able to find an example of how to do this without it.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve ComboBox#getValue() without any data binding.